# Brace expansion with $@ arguments

Tags: bash, variable-expansion, brace-expansion

Suppose I call a script with 3 arguments, `a`, `abc`, and `xyz` such that `$@` contains these three arguments.

Suppose I want to call write a command:

```
command fooa fooabc fooxyz bara barabc barxyz
```

How would I accomplish that?

I don't think `{foo,bar}$@` or `{foo,bar}{$@}` work since brace expansion happens before `$@` is expanded.

Comment: In zsh, `{foo,bar}"$@"` does actually work this way. Unfortunately not in bash.

Comment: @Kevin Almost. That expands to `fooa bara fooabc barabc fooxyz barxyz`.

Comment: @chepner I guess if order matters for that particular command...

Comment: With a second array, you can preserve the order in `zsh`: `fb=(foo bar); echo "${^fb[@]}$@"`. (There's probably a way to do this without an explicit array, but this is probably enough off-topic speculation in the comments :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use:

```
command "${@/#/foo}" "${@/#/bar}"
```

This uses the substitute variant of [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).  The `#` anchors the match to the start of the parameter.

```
$ set -- a abc xyz
$ echo command "${@/#/foo}" "${@/#/bar}"
command fooa fooabc fooxyz bara barabc barxyz
$
```

---

> Is there a way to scale this for larger `{foo,bar,baz,...}$@` or `{foo,bar}{123,456}$@`?

Yes, but you would end up using arrays:

```
$ set -- a abc xyz
$ args=( "$@" )
$ for prefix in foo bar baz who why; do prefixed1+=( "${args[@]/#/$prefix}" ); done
$ echo command "${prefixed1[@]}"
command fooa fooabc fooxyz bara barabc barxyz baza bazabc bazxyz whoa whoabc whoxyz whya whyabc whyxyz
$
```

Or (noting that you have to get the sequencing correct):

```
$ for prefix in 123 456; do prefixed1+=( "${args[@]/#/$prefix}" ); done
$ for prefix in foo bar; do prefixed2+=( "${prefixed1[@]/#/$prefix}" ); done
$ echo command "${prefixed2[@]}"
command foo123a foo123abc foo123xyz foo456a foo456abc foo456xyz bar123a bar123abc bar123xyz bar456a bar456abc bar456xyz
$
```

Note that this preserves spaces in arguments:

```
$ unset prefixed1 prefixed2
$ set -- 'a b' 'x y z'
$ args=( "$@" )
$ for prefix in 'p p-' '123 456 '; do prefixed1+=( "${args[@]/#/$prefix}" ); done
$ echo command "${prefixed1[@]}"
command p p-a b p p-x y z 123 456 a b 123 456 x y z
$ for prefix in 'foo 1-' 'bar 2-'; do prefixed2+=( "${prefixed1[@]/#/$prefix}" ); done
$ echo command "${prefixed2[@]}"
command foo 1-p p-a b foo 1-p p-x y z foo 1-123 456 a b foo 1-123 456 x y z bar 2-p p-a b bar 2-p p-x y z bar 2-123 456 a b bar 2-123 456 x y z
$ printf "[%s]\n" "${prefixed2[@]}"
[foo 1-p p-a b]
[foo 1-p p-x y z]
[foo 1-123 456 a b]
[foo 1-123 456 x y z]
[bar 2-p p-a b]
[bar 2-p p-x y z]
[bar 2-123 456 a b]
[bar 2-123 456 x y z]
$
```

And the first loop could be:

```
for prefix in 'p p-' '123 456 '; do prefixed1+=( "${@/#/$prefix}" ); done
```

without using the `${args[@]}` array.

Comment: Thanks!  Is there a way to scale this for larger `{foo,bar,baz,...}$@` or `{foo,bar}{123,456}$@`?